# iPad presentModalViewController appears in wrong position

Tags: ios, ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller

First of, I get the feeling apple really doesnt like us optimizing apps for landscape view.

After struggling with my app for 2 days I finally convince it to always and only show in Landscape mode. I even convinced the UIViewController that I present with presentModalViewController to appear in landscape as well. So far so good...

The position of the UIViewController that I present with UIModalPresentationFormSheet is all the way to the bottom right (with the ipad in Landscape positition). I cannot get it to move to the center like it should. Does anyone have any ideas why and or how this works and how I can make it apear in the right position?

EDIT: Added code, this code is called from a UIViewController when a button is pushed.

```
- (void) buttonPushed
{
    pickerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [pickerViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    _pickerCustomers = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22,20,380,216)];
    _pickerCustomers.delegate = self;
    _pickerCustomers.dataSource = self;
    [_pickerCustomers setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    [pickerViewController.view addSubview:_pickerCustomers];

    _btnPickerDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [_btnPickerDone setFrame: CGRectMake(300,250,98,45)];
    [_btnPickerDone setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pickerViewController.view addSubview:_btnPickerDone];

    pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController:pickerViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful I think.  For instance are you calling it from rootview or detail view?

Comment: @Alan Added the code that calls for the viewController to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with the little "autoposition springs" on the layout IB?  Probably you have it attached to the bottom and right, simply remove those attachments.

Here's a link for you: http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Layout/Layout.html

Can also be done in code if you like.

Comment: in this case the presentation mode is what determines where it should appear.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that was handled the same way!